# Замена слова в списке, который лежит в .txt файле

Tags: python, файлы

У меня есть код, который достаёт из файла users.txt строку, в которой содержится id пользователя (это бот для VK на longpoll), далее он эту строку преобразовывает в список и меняет значение этого списка под индексом 1. **Сама проблема**: *почему программа не меняет значение списка под индексом 1 в файле users.txt?* 
Вот сам код:

```
 `FIND = str(event.user_id)
  renick = open("users.txt", encoding="utf-8")
  for line in renick:
    if FIND in line:
       print("HEllo")
       words = line.split()
       words[1] = "nick"
       break
  renick.close()`
```

Comment: Потому что и не должна. Вы открываете файл **на чтение**, считываете из него данные, изменяете их, но **не записываете** обратно в файл.

Comment: А как это реализовать? Я открывал и с mode="w", и со всеми остальными - ничего. Как тогда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER = ' '
lines = []

with open('users.txt', encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

for n, line in enumerate(lines):
    words = line.strip().split(DELIMITER)
    if len(words) < 2:
        continue
    if words[1] == FIND:
        words[1] = 'nick'
        lines[n] = DELIMITER.join(words) + '\n'
        break

with open('users.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    fh.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не записываете считанные данные из файла обратно в файл, поэтому в нем и нет новой информации.
Чтобы записать информацию в файл, откройте его со знаком `'w'`. Пример записи списка в файл:

```
f = open('file_name.txt', 'w')
f.write("\n".join(list).join("\n"));
```

Comment: Мне нужно заменить элемент в списке.